# How to weight by ratio of two variables with geom_histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Package I'm working with:**

- ggplot2

**Starting data set I'm working with:**

```
Group_Size       Group_Premium   Group_Claims
26               24544.01        18181.25
6                10017.12        7604.51         
13               12694.34        8787.00
98               90916.20        67166.73
27               31113.72        27180.83
```

**What am I trying to do?**

I'm trying to create something akin to a histogram.

I'd like to bin by Group_Size such that I have bins 0-20, 21-40, 41-60, etc [bins of width 20]. So Group_Size bins would be my x-axis of this "histogram".

I'd like the y-axis to plot sum(Group_Claims)/sum(Group_Premium). So, for example, in the dummy data set above, I'd want the 0-20 bin to have the following y value:

```
(7604.51 + 8787.00) / (10017.12 + 12694.34) = 0.7217
```

**The code I've tried so far...**

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Group_Size = c(26, 6, 13, 98, 27),
                 Group_Premium = c(24544.01, 10017.12, 12694.34, 90916.20, 31113.72),
                 Group_Claims = c(18181.25, 7604.51, 8787.00, 67166.73, 27180.83))

my_plot <- ggplot(
  data=df
  , aes(x=Group_Size, weights=Group_Claims/Group_Premium)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=20, boundary = 0)

my_plot
```

However, this doesn't work as I want it to. It does sum(Group_Claims/Group_Premium) as the y-value rather than sum(Group_Claims)/sum(Group_Premium). How can I achieve what I want? Thanks, all.

Comment: Good question, I think. One thing you could do that may make this even more easily reproducible/testable by others is to run `dput()` on the data set - and then to add *that* code, perhaps in addition to the code that you added. Then folks can enter that directly and use it.

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg That makes sense. I've edited my post with code that makes it easier for anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```
df %>%
    mutate(binGroupSize = cut(Group_Size, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20))) %>%
    group_by(binGroupSize) %>%
    summarise(ratioSum = sum(Group_Claims) / sum(Group_Premium)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(binGroupSize, ratioSum)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Explanation: Use `cut` to bin `Group_Size` (with bin width = 20), then group by `binGroupSize` and `summarise` the ratio of the sums of `Group_Claims` and `Group_Premium`; then plot as barplot.

---

Or if you want to keep the "empty" levels:

```
df %>%
    mutate(binGroupSize = cut(Group_Size, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20))) %>%
    group_by(binGroupSize) %>%
    summarise(ratioSum = sum(Group_Claims) / sum(Group_Premium)) %>%
    complete(binGroupSize) %>%
    ggplot(aes(binGroupSize, ratioSum)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: No worries @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero; glad to help.